# Error function of multivariate Gaussian

Tags: linear-algebra, real-analysis, special-functions

I'm trying to prove that a sequence of functions $(k_N)_{N\in\mathbb{N}}$

$$k_N(\vec{y}):=e^{-N^2r(\vec{y},Q\vec{y})}\sqrt{\frac{r}{\pi}}^kN^{k}$$

where $r>0$, $k>2$ and

**Edit**: I have forgot to say, that $k\in\mathbb{N}$ is the size of the matrix $Q$ i.e. $Q$ is $k\times k$. This means that $\det Q=0$ and $Q$ is positive semidefinte.

I have also changed $k$ from beeing $>0$ to $k>2$.

**End of the Edit**

$$Q:=\left(\begin{array}{cccccccc}
(1-\frac{1}{k})& -\frac{1}{k} & -\frac{1}{k} & \cdots  & -\frac{1}{k} \\
-\frac{1}{k} & (1-\frac{1}{k}) & -\frac{1}{k} & \cdots & -\frac{1}{k} \\
\vdots & \ddots & & &\vdots \\
-\frac{1}{k} & \dots &  &-\frac{1}{k}  &(1-\frac{1}{k}) 
\end{array}\right)$$

goes to a delta function when $N\to\infty$. What I'm missing ist showing, that given $\varepsilon>0$ and $\eta>0$ there exists $n_0$ such that $\forall n>n_0$

$$\idotsint_{|\vec{x}|>\eta}k_n(\vec{x})d\vec{x}<\varepsilon$$.

I was looking for some expression for the error function of multivariate gaussians, but could find nothing of the sort. Is there a nice way of representing the error functions so that I don't have to diagonalize $Q$ and treat the function as several independent gaussians?

Thanks!

Comment: What is $r(\beta')$ and what is $\beta'$?

Comment: $r(\beta')$ is a constant of my system. I'm working with a fixed $\beta'$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\newcommand\R{\mathbb R}$Let us write $x$ for $\vec x$ and $t$ for $\eta$. Then
$$\int_{x\in\R^k\colon|x|>t}k_n(x)\,dx=\infty$$
for all real $t>0$.

Indeed, we can write
$$Q=I_k-\frac1k\,1_k1_k^T,$$
where the matrix $I_k$ is the $k\times k$ identity matrix and $1_k$ is the $1\times k$ column matrix with unit entries, that is, $1_K=e_1+\dots+e_k$, where $(e_1,\dots,e_k)$ is the standard basis of $\R^k$. So, $Q$ is the matrix of the orthogonal projector onto the orthogonal complement -- say $V$ -- of (the span of) the vector $1_k$; in particular, $Q1_k=0$.

Fix any orthonormal basis $(b_1,\dots,b_k)$ of $\R^d$ such that $b_1=1_k/\sqrt k$ (so that $(b_2,\dots,b_k)$ is an orthonormal basis of $V$).
Let $(x_1,\dots,x_k)$ denote the coordinates of an arbitrary vector $x\in\R^d$ in the orthonormal basis $(b_1,\dots,b_k)$. Then
$$(x,Qx)=x_2^2+\dots+x_k^2.$$
Therefore and because the Lebesgue measure is spherically invariant, for all real $t>0$ we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\int_{x\in\R^k dx\,\colon|x|>t}dx\, k_n(x) \\
&\ge\int_{x\in\R^k\colon x_1>t}dx\, k_n(x) \\
&=\int_t^\infty dx_1\int_\R dx_2\cdots\,\int_\R dx_k 
\exp\{-n^2r(x_2^2+\dots+x_k^2)\}\Big(\sqrt{\frac{r}{\pi}}\Big)^k n^{2k}
=\infty,
\end{aligned}$$
because the inner $(k-1)$-fold integral is a strictly positive real number not depending on $x_1$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have realized that the definition of $k_N$ is wrong. The function should be normalized.

I'm going to edit the definition.

Comment: Clearly, no strictly positive normalizing factor can possibly help here.

Comment: After reading this comment I was really confused about what went wrong with my idea. I have just seen, that I forgot to mention an important detail: $k\in\mathbb{N}$ is also the size of the matrix, so that $Q$ is positive semi-definite.

I'm terribly sorry for the misunderstanding. I have been working on the problem leading to this question for so long, that it didn't even occurred to me to mention.

Comment: I'm editing the question again, but your clever decomposition of the matrix has already helped me a great deal!

Comment: I did not have a problem with $k$ denoting the dimension and $k_n$ denoting the kernel. The problem is with the fact that $Q$ is a **singular** (positive-semidefinite) matrix, rather than a positive-definite one.

Comment: Well, I guess this solves what I was trying. I'm going to try something else here. The problem is restricted to positive integers as components of $\vec{y}$, but I was trying to extend it to $\mathbb{R}$.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I have just realized, that my problem is defined only in the orthogonal complement $V$ you defined, because I'm working with a convolution of this function. I will work on it. Thanks for the comments!

Comment: That would make more sense. But then you would have to define the measure on $V$ over which you want to integrate.

Comment: I'll work on the definitions over this month and try to organize the problem more rigorously. Thanks again for the comments, it has helped me think about the details of this, which is going to be in my master thesis.